# Python: TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
def search():
    os.chdir("C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/MyFiles")
    files = os.listdir(".")
    os.mkdir("C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/FilesWithString")
    string = input("Please enter the website your are looking for (in lower case):")
    for x in files:
        inputFile = open(x, "r")
        try:
            content = inputFile.read().lower
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            continue
        inputFile.close()
        if string in content:
            shutil.copy(x, "C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/FilesWithString")
```

which always gives this error:

```
line 80, in search
    if string in content:
TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable
```

can someone shed some light on why.

thans

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Change the line

```
content = inputFile.read().lower
```

to

```
content = inputFile.read().lower()
```

Your original line assigns the built-in function lower to your variable content instead of calling the function `str.lower` and assigning the return value which is definitely not iterable.

Comment: especially in this case pythons error messages could be slightly more helpful :-/

Answer (score 5):

You're using

```
content = inputFile.read().lower
```

instead of

```
content = inputFile.read().lower()
```

ie you're getting the function lower and not the return value from lower.

In effect what you're getting is:

```
>>> 
>>> for x in "HELLO".lower:
...     print x
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```